# Qual a utilidade do console.dir() em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
console.dir(body)
```

Bom, será retornado uma lista interativa das propriedades do objeto, mas qual é a utilidade disso, o que estou querendo dizer é que podemos chamar diretamente no método `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` que será retornado o mesmo resultado.

Alem da economia de código existe alguma outra utilidade para essa função?

Comment: Uma bela informação sobre esse método: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console/dir e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `console.log()` e o `console.dir()`, hoje, fazem as mesmas coisas. Porém, durante algum tempo, no firefox, o `dir` era encarregado de imprimir a árvore de elementos, enquanto o `log` era encarregado de imprimir apenas um `toString()` do elemento.

É importante também atentar para a [ressalva que pode na documentatação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console/dir):

> ! Non-standard
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Ou seja, o método `console.dir()` não é um método padrão, o que pode acarretar problemas em determinados navegadores que não foram implementados, sendo desaconselhável seu uso em produção.

Na prática, hoje, com a mudança da forma que o `console.log` teve na sua implementação, o `console.dir` se tornou desnecessário.

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver depurando o código por exemplo de um Array e utilizar o console.log ele vai te dar o estado do objeto naquele momento em que vc usou o console.log.

Se você utilizar o console.dir você verá que independente de onde vc tenha colocado ele no código ele irá mostrar o estado atual do objeto.

Crie um Array com alguns objetos
use o console.log para ver o array detalhado e em seguida o console.dir do mesmo array.
Depois faça algumas alterações no array e veja o que acontece.